# What does 'on questions' mean?

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

In the medal system of [this very site](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/badges/44/electorate), there is such a golden medal, *Electorate*, whose description is as follows.

> Vote on 600 questions and 25% or more of total votes are on questions.

What does 'on questions' mean?

My first impression is that it means 25% or more of total votes are dedicated to *questions* rather than *answers*. But 'vote on 600 questions' already states that the 600 votes are dedicated to *questions* rather than *answers*. How does that make sense?

Comment: Did you mean, in your question, 'What does 'on **questions**' mean? The phrase 'on question' does not appear in the medal description that you quoted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The phrase is "votes on questions". In this case, the preposition is determined more by "votes" than by the next noun.

One votes *on* things. You vote on who will be the next president, on which Thai restaurant is the best in town, on which pizza toppings to order as a family.

In the case of upvotes and downvotes, one votes on (whether) a question is good or bad.

As Michael Harvey said, this is implicitly contrasted with votes on answers or comments.

Answer (score 2):

The text says that to gain the Electorate badge, two things are necessary:

(1) a person must have voted on at least 600 questions, and

(2) at least 25% of the person's total votes must have been **votes on questions**.

The phrase 'on question' does not appear in the medal description quoted.

Comment: Wouldn't it be at MOST 2400 times in total?  If you voted on 600 questions out of 2500 total votes, your votes-on-questions rate is only 24%.

Comment: Whatever. If someone had voted 39,999 times in total and 9,999 were on questions, and they voted once more on a question, the system awards the badge.

Comment: If they voted 600 times on questions, they get the badge if 600 is 25% or more of their total votes. If not the system waits.

Answer (score -2):

The answer Michael Harvey gave in the comment section is flawed in an additional manner. (Beyond being in the comment section.) It did not define the term for which a definition was requested. It was, thus, not "on question." (Insert ironic emoji here.)

"On question" means something that is attached to, related to, or on the subject of the question being discussed.

For this web site, a vote "on question" (or "on *a* question") is a vote registered by clicking on the up or down button attached to the question. Alternative possibilities are to click on the button attached to an answer (a vote on an answer), or to click the up-vote or flag on a comment (a vote on a comment) under the question or one of the answers.

In other contexts "on question" will have different meanings. In the context of a discussion of a specific question, "on question" means discussion that is on topic in relation to the question. Example: The debate question is "Should comments contain answers?" An "on question" statement would be "The rules of this web site say that it should not."

Comment: Where does 'on question' ('question' singular) appear in the problem text quoted by the OP? It only appears in the title, and is almost certainly a typo.

Comment: It also appears in the question. "What does 'on question' mean?"  Also, nice of you to remove the comment I cited.

Comment: OP has edited question. It's about 'on questions'.